# Two "text" fields in Android Studio (visual layout editor)

Tags: android, xml

Just that: i see two "text" fields in androidstudio layout visual editor, and i'm wondering what's the difference between them.
[image]

i mean that i see 2 "text" on in the property window of a textView (see image, on the right)
and in the autogenerated xml file it appears like this 
[image]

so what's the deal with `android:text` and `tools:text` xml attributes?
If anyone can answer, thaks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please post your code in text rather than images.

Answer (score 3):

`tools` namespace used for layout preview, so it will render in preview but not be rendered on device.

You can learn more here: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html)